# An advanced adversary is targeting you - now what? - so what?

Tags: physical

Consider the following:

An advanced adversary is targeting you.
He has the ability to watch most if not all of your network connections and the ones in the neighbourhood. He is sitting on numerous zero days. He can also follow you physically to whereever he wants and knows generally a lot about you and your habits.

You could of course try to buy new hardware, install some IDS but why?
Since you're possibly surveilled all the time it is hard to securely bootstrap a system. You maybe can lower the risk here and there a bit but ultimately you wont approach the security level you like to have. (At least I don't). It would also be hard to get a baseline of what would be considered normal network traffic or application behaviour.
In contrast, you would risk even more compromise, waste resources, ...

Is their any point in changing your behaviour? Since they already hacked your system(s) it does not really matter if they do so again.
So, what to do? Read a book, get some games to play (offline), join the Foreign Legion?

Comment: You have to state your threat model before this even becomes remotely answerable. Generally, you'd have to suffer through some restrictions in how you use electronics. Deliver information by passing a physical flash drive rather than sending an email (even encrypted, if you assume a GnuPG 0day), for example.

Comment: Advanced adversaries do not target one just because they have too much time and money to spend. They have a specific goal, like stealing information etc. What you need to do depends on what there goal is - for example by making all the sensitive information unreachable.

Comment: What would you be trying to prevent? If they're doing it "just because they can" then I don't think there's much to worry about. If they have some malicious intent, then it becomes a much different question.

Comment: "Advanced adversaries do not target one just because they have too much time and money to spend." Citation needed.     Of course the attacker has some kind of motivation. However, it is not always possible to change something on your side to the extend that it would make sense or be secure enough.

Comment: I would need to know when the attacker has what he wants or gives up. This is hard to know, hence I always assume the worst.  @forest "Deliver information by passing a physical flash drive rather than sending an email (even encrypted, if you assume a GnuPG 0day), for example."   Pointless if they could get the data possibly by stealing the stick.

Comment: @hangingandchilling: I recommend that you make yourself familiar with risk analysis and risk management: know what you need to protect and what its worth and then invest the necessary amount of time, intelligence and money to protect it. Real valuable things might simply be kept completely offline so that physical access is needed - which a remote attacker does not have even if he is advanced. Sure, this might impact usability for yourself but this is part of the balance between costs and remaining risk. This kind of risk management is also done outside cyber security, i.e. in real life.

Comment: @hangingandchilling: Even an advanced attacker has no unlimited time, money and resources. Even if he might have some 0days these are expensive and once used they might be burned forever (i.e. some AV detects something suspicious and reports home for detailed analysis - thus making the 0day known to white hats). So even an advanced attacker needs to be careful how his resources are spend. He will not use expensive attacks if the target is not worth it.

Comment: I always get a little upset when relevant questions get close voted.  Although many people have paranoia about being targeted by an advanced target these situations can and do happen.  A checklist should be created in case you feel that you are one of those people.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Risk: Go from the current 99% compromise to 100%     Risk management: see OP, not sure if it makes sense.   "and then invest the necessary amount of time, intelligence and money to protect it." I doubt you can't protect yourself or family, friends, ... against a well funded adversary.   "which a remote attacker does not have even if he is advanced." as mentioned in the OP the attacker is also local. Physical insecurity is more or less a lost case. Once they know who you are ...

Comment: "Even an advanced attacker has no unlimited time, money and resources" Yeah. Of course also the NSA has no unlimited budget but if you compare it to the budget of the average Joe it looks like almost unlimited. Regarding the loss of zero days: True in general. However, when looking at  securely bootstrapping your system, setting everything up (again)  you risk getting from the 99% to 100% percent. This makes things a bit complicated. Not to mention that bootstrapping a system in a secure way requires some resources itself and might be counteracted by the adversary.

Comment: @OP you just defined the today's government.

Comment: Except the government has been harrassing me a lot less. Yadayada, I know this is the moral of the story. However, since I know my adversary also a bit and yet being the person I am I will never risk making my security worse, which I could possible do when doing more or less anything (except hangingandchilling). Guess what, my intention was even to actually implement IDS, bla bla bla all the stuff. Some I even already had setup or was in the course of setting up. But then ...

Comment: What is your question exactly?Does defence matter when an all powerfull government with all resources try and attack you?Is that the question?